# Is there a list of Creature traits/abilities?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

I am trying to build a simplified system for creating creatures

For 3rd Edition there are lists of all the special abilities/powers/actions that a creature/monster may be able to employ.

For example "[Special Abilities](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm)".

Is there a comparable list or list made for 5th edition creatures?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 5e Dungeon Master's Guide, pg.273 "Creating a Monster", if you flip to pages 280-281 there's a huge table of "Monster Features".

Comment: That table is not exhaustive- 5e expects creatures to have unique features

Answer (score 4):

**The DMG has a Monster Features index (DMG p. 280)**

It may not be exactly what you're after, but it should be a good starting point.